# pgfplots: Is "scale only axis" only necessary for documents but not for standalone?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scaling, legend, axis

Assumed we have this kind of code:

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,scale only axis]
    \addplot {2^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

- I don't get the point what `scale only axis` is doing exactly and when I should use it?
- Is this key only necessary in case you put the diagram directly in a document (e.g. `article`, `book`, etc.) or do you also need this key for `standalone` images?

Comment: Read page 293 of the `pgfplots` package manual.

Comment: 1) if you say `[height=10cm,width=10cm]` the entire graphic with the labels will be `10 x 10 cm`, but if you add `scale only axis` the labels are not considered and only the plot part will be `10 x 10 cm`. 2) This is valid for `standalone` or not, but in `standalone` do not use `\textheight` and `\textwidth`.